# Azure AD Access token Authorization

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, authorization

Is there any way to set custom permissions in an azure ad for access tokens? For example Service provider "A" has access to Market "SE" and "DE".

I have not seen any solution using Group/Scope/Role authorization.

Comment: What did you mean by `Market "SE" and "DE"` could you please explain your expectations a bit more.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron for example in my API I want users to only have access to specific markets. "User A" should have access to data from market "Sweden" and "Germany", while "User B" should only have access to data from market "Sweden".

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT not quite, unfortunately. For example, If I create a role: File.Read they will be able to read data. However, how can I say that User A should only read files in my database from Market "SE" while user B"

Comment: For that purpose, you will have to enable RBAC based permissions for that particular user's access to that database or you can also configure an application to access that database using the connection string and access keys also. Or you can also use the delegated permissions in this case.

Answer (score 0):

•   Custom permissions in an Azure AD access token can be set with respect to the user or application requesting the token, i.e., on the IDP side (Azure AD) when an application is registered for authentication and authorization purposes with Azure AD, we have the privilege of configuring the various app roles and assigning users and administrators to that application.

•   Thus, we cannot customize permissions for an access token altogether, but we can authorize assigned permissions through that access token to a user or an application as below: -

a)  Defining a scope for the accessing user/application to access and read application API data in the access token.

[image: Expose an API]

b)  Defining an app role for assigning the user or application requesting access to the API by defining a custom defined role and assigning it along with scope parameter in the access token.

[image: App role]

c)  Assign the API that is hosted in Azure AD the requested permissions for the scope and app roles through admin consent or delegated user permissions by going to ‘Enterprise applications --> Select the application --> API permissions --> Add a permission --> Select the API --> Select the required scope --> Add permission --> Grant admin consent’

[image: API permissions]

Thus, we can leverage these two in conjunction to assign specific applications and users’ permissions to the API and pass these in access tokens for determining whether the user or application that has requested the token has the required privileges or not. Please refer the below link which refers to how the permissions can be asserted through an access token: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims

Kindly check the ‘scp’, ‘roles’ and ‘wids’ claims in this link with respect to the above and consented permissions for.